# Complex request with aggregated subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregation, netezza

I have a request for you. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT 
   client, 
   indicator, 
   replace(Month, 'M', '') AS new_Month,---Needed because of the letter M always present with the month column initially
   TO_DATE(Year||'-'||LPAD(new_Month,2,'00')||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD')AS Date , 
   description, 
   det_ind.transmitted, 
   det_ind.export_zip,
   amount
FROM indicators as ind
   join clients as cl
   on ind.code_cl=cl.code_cl
   join Detail_indicators as det_ind
   on ind.indicator=det_ind.code_ind
```

This code yields me a table that is like so:

| Client | Indicator | Date | Description | transmitted | export_zip | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TOTAL | ENT1 | 2018/11/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 24544 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/10/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 14666 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/09/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 53667 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/08/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 12789 |
| TOTAL | ARS2 | 2018/07/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 42779 |
| TOTAL | ARS2 | 2018/06/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 11223 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/05/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 15678 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/04/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 21446 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/03/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 92556 |
| TOTAL | ARS1 | 2018/02/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 13245 |
| APPLE | ENT1 | 2018/11/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 24544 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/10/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 14666 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/09/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 53667 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/08/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 12789 |
| APPLE | ARS2 | 2018/07/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 42779 |
| APPLE | ARS2 | 2018/06/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 11223 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/05/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 15678 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/04/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 21446 |
| APPLE | ARS1 | 2018/03/01 | Some text | Boolean | Boolean | 92556 |

Then I need to calculate a rate for each Client which is calculated like so:

```
sum(case when INDICATOR IN ('ARS1') then Amount else 0 end) as Received_money,
sum(case when INDICATOR IN ('ARS2') then Amount else 0 end) as Engaged_money
round(100*sum(Received_money)/sum(Engaged_money),2) as RATE_ENT1
```

The trick is that all lines with the indicator ENT1 needs a RATE_ENT1 value which is calcultated over the 4 months prior to the date associated with ENT1, which would be implemented with

```
add_months(Date,-4)
```

Now my question is: How could I write this to have all my ENT1 lines filled with the good result in RATE_ENT1 in one single request.

Comment: This is not SQL Server syntax

Comment: You are right sorry. Title has been updated.